# CSS: How do I put two div boxes on one another?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that has been created with a shop CMS. On the start page there are two div boxes on the same level that appear in the following order:

1. DIV-box "container" -> contains the image of a gold bar
2. DIV-box "custom_text" -> contains text

Here comes a screenshot: http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11ratd5&s=5#.Utm1FhCIXrc

My goal: Having the text appear next to the gold bar by putting the "custom_text" box onto the image "container" box. How can I achieve that with CSS?

Comment: Hint: if you know the `<h1>` size, you can do this very easily with `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <p>2 divs</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can put one div into another!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the width of the containing div and posting text to the side with another div.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it: I put the .imagemap inside the .container-div "absolute !important"...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the HTML was like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="inner-box">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

You can put two inner `<div>`s over each other by setting `position: absolute;`. An if you want to keep them in current position instead of sticking to top or other places, you should wrap it with an outer box and set `position: relative;` for the wrapper.

**CSS**

```
.outer-box {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-box {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you don't do `position: relative;` for outer box, the default position of inner boxes (`top:0; left:0;`) will become actual position of their closest parent with `relative` on the page or just `<body>`.